# Cannot catch error when error is from another function

Tags: javascript, npm, error-handling

This is my testing code

```
m = require("snakegame");
post = {x:5,y:5};
option = {pos:post};

try{
m(option);
}catch(err){
  alert(err.message);
}
```

This is the code in my package

```
import {Snake} from "./snake.js";
import {View} from "./view.js";
import {Map} from "./map.js";

function SnakeGame(option={n:10, refreshRate:200, cellSide : 10}){
//pos (deault {x:Math.floor(Math.random() * n), y:Math.floor(Math.random() * n)})
        if(!(option.hasOwnProperty('n'))) option.n = 10;
        if(!(option.hasOwnProperty('refreshRate'))) option.refreshRate = 200;
        if(!(option.hasOwnProperty('cellSide'))) option.cellSide = 10;
        if(!(option.hasOwnProperty('pos'))){
            option.pos = {x:Math.floor(Math.random() * option.n),y:Math.floor(Math.random() * option.n)};
        } else {
            if(option.pos.x > option.n -1  || option.pos.x < 0 ||option.pos.y > option.n - 1 || option.pos.y < 0){
                throw new Error("Start position out of range");
            }
        }
        const v = new View(option.n, option.cellSide);
        const s = new Snake(option.pos, option.n);
        const m = new Map(option.n, s, v);
        var keyBoard = "up";

        function fn(e){
            if(e.key==="ArrowUp") keyBoard = "up";
            if(e.key==="ArrowDown") keyBoard = "down";
            if(e.key==="ArrowRight") keyBoard = "right";
            if(e.key==="ArrowLeft") keyBoard = "left";
        }

        function movement(){
                if(keyBoard==="up") m.up();
                if(keyBoard==="down"){
                    throw new Error("cant go down");
                    m.down();
                }
                if(keyBoard==="left") m.left();
                if(keyBoard==="right") m.right();
        }
        window.setInterval(() => {
            document.addEventListener('keydown', fn);
            movement();
        }, option.refreshRate);

}


module.exports = SnakeGame;
```

I would just like the highlight code in the package `throw new Error("cant go down");`

Although I have a try catch in my testing code encapsulating the function call of my npm module. It don't seem to catch the the 'cant go down' error that is in the function movement, in my chrome browser it throws uncaught error cant go down. However, the program could catch the  "Start position out of range".

How to solve it.

Comment: `movement` is called by the browser itself (from the event queue where it has been placed by `setInterval`), so your `try/catch` block isn't in the call stack when the error is thrown

Comment: There are several mistakes in your code You are calling `document.addEventListener('keydown', fn);` in a `setInterval` thus registering an increasing amount of listeners over time. Since you're calling `movement` inside a `setInterval` it throws when your top-level code has already finished